# ruby class body inheritance

Tags: ruby, inheritance

I'd like to know if something like this is possible in ruby.

```
# file a.rb
class A
  puts self
end

# file b.rb
require 'a'
class B < A; end

# file run.rb
puts 'start'
require 'a'
puts 'between'
require 'b'
puts 'end'

# expected output
$ ruby run.rb
# => start
# => A
# => between
# => B
# => end

# what i've got
# => start
# => A
# => between
# => end
```

I'd like to puts class constant when it will be required. But i'd like to implement this once and then in child classes repeat this without touching code.

Comment: As far as I understand your question, this is default behavior of `require`. Did you try running your code?

Comment: Firstly i was playing with irb but now i tried to run it with separate files and still it not work as i want to.
I've added some debug puts in output of run class and i got this in result: `#=> start #=> A #=> between #=> end`
There should be `#=> B` before `#=> end` print.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not outputting B because the class A block, which contains `puts self` is already evaluated. It won't re-evaluate the body of class A when inheriting from it.

In broad strokes, you can think of a Ruby class as an array of hashes of methods to look up from. When you inherit a class, you push a new hash of methods in the lookup list.

That being said, the `Class#inherited` function will allow you to do what you're seeking:

```
class A
  def self.inherited(klass)
    puts klass
  end
end

class B < A
end
```

Also note the two related methods for modules: `Module#included` and `Module#extended`.

Comment: If you want this functionality but with old inheritance behavior you can set up an alias method in `class A` before overwriting `inherited`:  `alias_method :old_inherited, :inherited`. Then, after `puts klass` you can call `old_inherited`.